# I have a difficulty with my javascript

Tags: javascript, split, type-conversion

I have been making a simple program and when I run the function "convert()" it does not do anything. It is definitely a problem with the var data line because I have tried using // to make it a comment and it works. Please help me have this work. Here is my javascript code for convert():

```
    function convert(){
            var data = document.getElementById("inputArea").split(":");
            for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) { data[i] = +data[i]; }
            document.write("It works!");
    }
```

Comment: What do you expect from splitting an element? You probably want to split its value.

Comment: you'll probably want document.getElementById("inputArea").value

Comment: try splitting those 2 operations up. So, getElementbyID then on the next line try the split and see if the id is undefined or null by adding a breakpoint on the split line. Also what @elclanrs said about the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take the value of the input element and not the input itself. 
the right code :

```
function convert(){
        var data = document.getElementById("inputArea").value.split(":");
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) { data[i] = +data[i]; }
        document.write("It works!");
}
```